# Web scraping by navigating different tabs in web page and fetch data to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I have a link as:

```
url = "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm"
```

I want to navigate like:

```
1. Click on Losers Tab
2. Click on F&O Securities Tab
3. Fetch the result table data to Dataframe.
```

[image: Image_Data]

Comment: use Selenium for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See brower network tab, clear all and click on 1. Click on Losers Tab -> Click on F&O Securities Tab, you will see the `https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/losers/fnoLosers1.json` url request json response, which is a table data.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/losers/fnoLosers1.json'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

O/P:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "symbol": "RELINFRA",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "83.45",
      "highPrice": "86.80",
      "lowPrice": "72.70",
      "ltp": "73.45",
      "previousPrice": "84.90",
      "netPrice": "-13.49",
      "tradedQuantity": "4,28,81,500",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "33,782.05",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "12-Sep-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting\/Dividend Rs 9.50 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "DHFL",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "91.10",
      "highPrice": "93.20",
      "lowPrice": "80.10",
      "ltp": "83.25",
      "previousPrice": "93.95",
      "netPrice": "-11.39",
      "tradedQuantity": "8,36,01,446",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "71,303.67",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "19-Jun-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting \/ Dividend- Rs 2.50 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "RELCAPITAL",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "110.45",
      "highPrice": "111.55",
      "lowPrice": "97.55",
      "ltp": "100.00",
      "previousPrice": "111.85",
      "netPrice": "-10.59",
      "tradedQuantity": "3,62,53,302",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "37,616.43",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "12-Sep-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting\/Dividend Rs 11 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "PCJEWELLER",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "68.00",
      "highPrice": "68.85",
      "lowPrice": "60.30",
      "ltp": "62.00",
      "previousPrice": "67.80",
      "netPrice": "-8.55",
      "tradedQuantity": "3,27,80,219",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "21,051.46",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "19-Sep-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting\/Dividend Re 0.50 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "JETAIRWAYS",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "133.00",
      "highPrice": "133.00",
      "lowPrice": "122.65",
      "ltp": "124.90",
      "previousPrice": "133.10",
      "netPrice": "-6.16",
      "tradedQuantity": "50,02,823",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "6,367.59",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "01-Aug-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "RPOWER",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "6.70",
      "highPrice": "6.70",
      "lowPrice": "5.95",
      "ltp": "6.20",
      "previousPrice": "6.60",
      "netPrice": "-6.06",
      "tradedQuantity": "9,77,85,958",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "6,082.29",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "12-Sep-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "JISLJALEQS",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "45.05",
      "highPrice": "46.10",
      "lowPrice": "42.50",
      "ltp": "42.60",
      "previousPrice": "45.05",
      "netPrice": "-5.44",
      "tradedQuantity": "1,70,42,429",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "7,498.67",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "12-Sep-2018",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting\/Dividend- Re 1 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "CGPOWER",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "34.20",
      "highPrice": "34.95",
      "lowPrice": "32.00",
      "ltp": "32.65",
      "previousPrice": "34.30",
      "netPrice": "-4.81",
      "tradedQuantity": "70,36,664",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "2,347.43",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "16-Aug-2016",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting (Book Closure Dates Revised)"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "MANAPPURAM",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "135.00",
      "highPrice": "136.55",
      "lowPrice": "122.60",
      "ltp": "132.65",
      "previousPrice": "137.75",
      "netPrice": "-3.70",
      "tradedQuantity": "2,59,15,128",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "33,881.44",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "27-May-2019",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Interim Dividend - Re 0.55 Per Share"
    },
    {
      "symbol": "APOLLOTYRE",
      "series": "EQ",
      "openPrice": "198.95",
      "highPrice": "199.95",
      "lowPrice": "191.45",
      "ltp": "192.40",
      "previousPrice": "199.50",
      "netPrice": "-3.56",
      "tradedQuantity": "26,45,450",
      "turnoverInLakhs": "5,171.33",
      "lastCorpAnnouncementDate": "23-Jul-2019",
      "lastCorpAnnouncement": "Annual General Meeting\/ Dividend - Rs 3.25 Per Share"
    }
  ],
  "time": "Jun 07, 2019 15:59:59"
}
```

**Update:**

```
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/losers/fnoLosers1.json'
response = requests.get(url)
jsonData = response.json()

print(json_normalize(jsonData['data']))
```

O/P:

```
  highPrice                               lastCorpAnnouncement lastCorpAnnouncementDate lowPrice  ... series      symbol tradedQuantity turnoverInLakhs
0     86.80  Annual General Meeting/Dividend Rs 9.50 Per Share              12-Sep-2018    72.70  ...     EQ    RELINFRA    4,28,81,500       33,782.05
1     93.20  Annual General Meeting / Dividend- Rs 2.50 Per...              19-Jun-2018    80.10  ...     EQ        DHFL    8,36,01,446       71,303.67
2    111.55    Annual General Meeting/Dividend Rs 11 Per Share              12-Sep-2018    97.55  ...     EQ  RELCAPITAL    3,62,53,302       37,616.43
3     68.85  Annual General Meeting/Dividend Re 0.50 Per Share              19-Sep-2018    60.30  ...     EQ  PCJEWELLER    3,27,80,219       21,051.46
4    133.00                             Annual General Meeting              01-Aug-2018   122.65  ...     EQ  JETAIRWAYS      50,02,823        6,367.59
5      6.70                             Annual General Meeting              12-Sep-2018     5.95  ...     EQ      RPOWER    9,77,85,958        6,082.29
6     46.10    Annual General Meeting/Dividend- Re 1 Per Share              12-Sep-2018    42.50  ...     EQ  JISLJALEQS    1,70,42,429        7,498.67
7     34.95  Annual General Meeting (Book Closure Dates Rev...              16-Aug-2016    32.00  ...     EQ     CGPOWER      70,36,664        2,347.43
8    136.55               Interim Dividend - Re 0.55 Per Share              27-May-2019   122.60  ...     EQ  MANAPPURAM    2,59,15,128       33,881.44
9    199.95  Annual General Meeting/ Dividend - Rs 3.25 Per...              23-Jul-2019   191.45  ...     EQ  APOLLOTYRE      26,45,450        5,171.33
```

Comment: Sir, I have one more question. Please find the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591881/web-scrap-with-multiple-inputs-and-collect-total-margin-required