# Web scrape with multiple inputs and collect Total Margin required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, request

I have a web link as:

```
url = "zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN"
```

Here input parameters with sample values for reference mentioned below:

```
Exchange - NFO
Product - Options
Symbol - DHFL 27-JUN-19
Option Type - Calls
Strike Price - 120
Net Qty appears automatically as 1500,
```

and Use **`SELL`** Button then Click **`ADD`** Button.

I want to collect the Total Margin required (in above case its **`Rs 49,308`**) which appears in the right end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use requests. If you observe your network, you can see that it is making a POST requests with selected payload. This is how I would do it:

```
from requests import Session

BASE_URL = 'https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN'

payload = {'action': 'calculate',
            'exchange[]': 'NFO',
            'product[]': 'FUT',
            'scrip[]': 'DHFL19AUG',
            'option_type[]': 'CE',
            'strike_price[]':120, 
            'qty[]': 4000,
            'trade[]': 'sell'
}



session = Session()

res = session.post(BASE_URL, data=payload)

data = res.json()

print(data)
```

I got the URL and Payload from observing network. This is what you will get as data in json form.[image]

Results in chrome and python
[image]

Just observe how chrome or firefox send and receive data. And reverse engineer with your requests.

Comment: Nice Answer Sir, Its fast also. Thanks

Comment: selenium ought to be the last resort in web scraping. In most of modern website, you can get data directly from jsons. No need of selenium or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Sir, Can you please help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602870/pull-data-from-web-link-to-dataframe

Comment: You can do pretty much the same. Someone else have answer your question already. If you want using requests, let me know the steps you took to reach that page, and we can create a GET call to retrieve data. with Pandas, you can read json directly

Comment: Sir, I am waiting for your answer using request.

Answer (score 1):

[website](https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN) link is dynamic rendering request table data. You should try `automation selenium library`. it allows you to scrape dynamic `rendering request(js or ajax)` page data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN")

# select  exchange   option of NFO
exchange = driver.find_element_by_name('exchange[]')
exchange.send_keys("NFO")

#  select product option of option
product = driver.find_element_by_name('product[]')
product.send_keys("OPT")

# select symbol  by option value
symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("scrip[]"))
symbol.select_by_value("DHFL19JUN")

# select  option Type  CELL option
optionType = driver.find_element_by_name('option_type[]')
optionType.send_keys("CE")

#add Strike price
strikePrice = driver.find_element_by_name('strike_price[]')
strikePrice.clear()
strikePrice.send_keys("120")

# add Net quantity
netQty = driver.find_element_by_name('qty[]')
netQty.clear()
netQty.send_keys("1500")

# select sell radio button
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name='trade[]'][value='sell']")[0].click()

#submit form
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit'][value='Add']")
submit.click()

time.sleep(2)

# scrape margin
margin = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".val.total")
print(margin.text)
```

where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` selenium web driver path.

**Download selenium web driver for chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**Selenium tutorial:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/