# Pull Data from web link to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I have a weblink:

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=1270&symbol=RELCAPITAL&symbol=RELCAPITAL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17"
```

I need to move the below table data to pandas dataframe.

[image: Data]

Comment: Please try to give more details about your problem and show what you have tried so far. This is not a service to order software solutions for customer problems. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How did you reach this page from https://www.nseindia.com/index_nse.htm?

Comment: Live Market => Option Chain => Equity Derivatives => Enter DHFL in "Search for Underlying Stock"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using requests, you would do:

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import Session

s = Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                         'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)

URL = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp'

params = {'symbolCode':940,
          'symbol':'DHFL',
          'instrument': 'OPTSTK',
          'date': '-',
          'segmentLink': 17
}


res = s.get(URL, params=params)

df = pd.read_html(res.content)[1]
```

Comment: Sir, I want to add this text message "Underlying Stock: RELCAPITAL 73.75  As on Jun 14, 2019 15:30:30 IST" as a column. How to retrive the text from the page and add into data frame. I have added my solution as below.

Comment: I have highlight the text in the page in my question picture.

Comment: see `print(pd.read_html(res.content)[0].loc[0, 1])` it is there :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use (create a helper browser):

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=1270&symbol=RELCAPITAL&symbol=RELCAPITAL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
```

---

```
df=pd.read_html(data)[1]
print(df.head())
```

---

```
CALLS                                                                  \
  Chart     OI Chng in OI Volume     IV    LTP Net Chng BidQty BidPrice   
0   NaN      -          -      -      -      -        -  37500    32.45   
1   NaN      -          -      -      -      -        -  37500    23.90   
2   NaN      -          -      -      -      -        -  37500    15.35   
3   NaN  15000          -      -      -  24.00        -  37500     6.65   
4   NaN  46500          -      5  10.59   4.00    -8.00   1500     4.00   

            ...     PUTS                                                \
  AskPrice  ... BidPrice AskPrice AskQty Net Chng   LTP      IV Volume   
0    52.55  ...        -     1.20   3000        -     -       -      -   
1    51.75  ...        -     1.20   3000        -     -       -      -   
2    40.20  ...     1.00     1.10   1500     0.60  1.10  168.46     21   
3    20.25  ...     2.50     2.55   1500     0.60  2.00  150.32     47   
4     5.00  ...     5.35     6.00   9000     3.30  6.10  147.49    115   


  Chng in OI      OI Chart  
0          -       -   NaN  
1          -       -   NaN  
2     -10500  135000   NaN  
3     -22500  192000   NaN  
4     -34500  292500   NaN  

[5 rows x 23 columns]
```

Comment: You could have requests instead of urllib, Makes things easier, But yeah. This does the same job i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import Session

#############################################
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 50000)
#############################################

s = Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                         'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)

URL = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp'
params = {'symbolCode':940,'symbol':'DHFL','instrument': 'OPTSTK','date': '-','segmentLink': 17}
res = s.get(URL, params=params)
df = pd.read_html(res.content)[1]
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(-1)
df = df.iloc[2:len(df)-1].reset_index(drop=True)

df.columns = ['C_Chart','C_OI','C_Chng_in_OI','C_Volume','C_IV','C_LTP','C_Net_Chng','C_BidQty','C_BidPrice','C_AskPrice','C_AskQty','Strike_Price','P_BidQty','P_BidPrice','P_AskPrice','P_AskQty','P_Net_Chng','P_LTP','P_IV','P_Volume','P_Chng_in_OI','P_OI','P_Chart']

df = df[['C_LTP','C_BidQty','C_BidPrice','Strike_Price']]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to pull the table data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=1270&symbol=RELCAPITAL&symbol=RELCAPITAL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17'

r = requests.get(url)

data = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1])

print(df)
```

Another way is behind:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=1270&symbol=RELCAPITAL&symbol=RELCAPITAL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17'

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs=dict(id="octable"))
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    if bool(cols):
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols #if ele
                     ]) # Get rid of empty values
    else:
        cols = row.find_all('th')

        cols_2 = []

        for ele in cols:
            e = ele.text.strip()
            cols_2.append(e)

            colspan =  int(ele.attrs.get('colspan', 0))

            if bool(colspan):
                for i in range(1, colspan):
                    cols_2.append('')

        data.append(cols_2)

print(data)

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```